# Generalization of direct product in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, direct-product

Let $G_1$, $G_2$ and $H$ be groups and $\phi_1: H \to G_1$ and $\phi_2: H \to G_2$ two monomorphisms. Consider the group $(G_1 \times G_2)/N$ where $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing the set $\{\big( \phi_1(h),\phi_2(h)\big)~|~h \in H\}$ $($here $G_1 \times G_2$ is direct product of groups$)$.

I want to know does this kind of "product" has some standard name. Can someone give some references? I want to know about their "properties".

I know I am not precise but any kind of help will be appreciated. Moreover, if someone has better title for this question please do the needful.

Comment: It looks very similar to the amalgated product (for free products instead of cartesian product). But you probably knew that already.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it.

Comment: It's not an amalgamated direct product, as that would mod out by the normal closure of the elements $(\phi_1(h),\phi_2(h)^{-1})$ (so that $\phi_1(h)$ and $\phi_2(h)$ are identified int he quotient). Dare I ask how this came about in the first place? What do you hope this construction to achieve?